# Diffenrence in int16 and int64

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, google-colaboratory

Why is it that setting the dtype = np.int64 while creating a black image, I cannot draw a circle on the image, while with dtype = np.int16 I can draw the circle on the black image.

```
black_img = np.zeros(shape = (512,512,3),dtype = np.int64)
```

```
cv2.circle(img = black_img,center = (400,100),radius = 50,color = (255,0,0),thickness = 8)
```

Output:
<UMat 0x7fe2a48da430>

```
plt.imshow(black_img)
```

The imshow() function shows the black image without the circle

**While with dtype = np.int16**

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       ...,

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=int16)
```

Please explain. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV drawing functions work with matrices of specific formats.

They are enumerated [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/d9e/classcv_1_1__OutputArray.html#details). Note that there is no format with 64 bit integer pixels, so OpenCV cannot draw using such matrix.